# Writing own convolutional layer in Keras from scratch

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I would like to create my own layer in Keras. To be more precision I would like to create simple convolution layer using only NumPy library(without TensorFlow part). I have some reasons for do that - first, for learning something new and second I have some idea how to modify that layer, so I have to write it from scratch. To make problem easier we can assume that I need only convolutional layer with 3x3 kernel size and default for others parameters.

I know I have to base on: https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/

In `def build(self, input_shape):` section I have to add weights. Convolutional layer needs `filters` times kernel matrix with 3x3 size.

In `def call(self, x):` section I can use that weights. But I have some problems with that.

## Problems:

1. I need to get something like sliding through the input - typical convolutional layer task(moving 3x3 matrix through  image). But I can't do that because `x` in `def call(self, x):` have `?` or `None` in first value in `shape`. I know it is batch_size, but I can't use loop on that tensor because of that. So how can I get all data(numbers) from `x` to make some operations using them?
2. Maybe you have some general tips how can I make my own Convolutional Layer from scratch in Keras?

The problem for me is not to write Convolutional Layer in numpy(there is materials about that - for example: https://github.com/Eyyub/numpy-convnet ) but to marge it with Keras without using TensorFlow backend.

Comment: You have a big conceptual problem here, you cannot make a Keras layers using numpy, as Keras uses symbolic tensors and automatic differentiation, numpy doesn't work with that.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Do you recommend some other popular frameworks, methods or whatever that can help me do that without writing everything from scratch - only that Convolutional layer?